# Discord.js Embed Message giving errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

My code: https://pastebin.com/MTH5Fcm7

When i run the command `?help` it gives this error:

(node:20460) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Uncaught DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using the latest version of discord.js (v13) to send an embed you have to do `<channel>.send({embeds: [array of embeds]})`-